# A synonym for 'army' that does not carry the military connotation?

Tags: synonyms

Usually people relate 'army' with the military connotation.

But sometimes you can say '**army of robots**' which not always you mean they've military backgrounds or they're armed, but friendly one. Another example includes 'Army of Jesus' or 'Salvation Army', and of course they've nothing to do with weapons and real army either.

Is there any alternative term which aims to describe the huge number of entities (like people or robots) in similar matter as 'army', but without being ambiguous that it has something to do with military, but to not lessen its meaning of its force?

Comment: A _host_ still connotes an army, but does not need to mean one. Look up synonyms of (this sense of) 'host', eg horde, multitude.

Comment: *synonyms:* crowd, swarm, multitude, horde, host, mob, gang, throng, stream, mass, body, band, troop, legion, flock, herd, pack, drove, sea, array; *literary:* myriad

Comment: legion of robots, swarm of robots, multitude of robots,a flock, an array, a sea of, a mob, a throng...

Comment: Legion would be the right word I think.

Comment: @kenorb Except of course that *legion* is a military term having a similar meaning to *army*.

Comment: "Army".  One might say, eg, that "an army of accountants" pored over the books of the corporation.

Comment: [The Salvation Army](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Salvation_Army) deliberately courted a military image -- "soldiers in God's Army."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer to a **swarm of robots** *(credit to @P.Obertelli)*.

See Wikipedia's [Swarm Robotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_robotics)

> Example: "There is something magical about seeing 1,000 robots move,
>   when humans are not operating any of them. In a new study published in
>   Science, researchers have achieved just that. *This swarm of 1,000
>   robots* can assemble themselves into complex shapes without the need
>   for a central brain or a human controller. [*[source]*](http://robohub.org/thousand-robot-swarm-self-assembles-into-arbitrary-shapes/)

For a group of persons, you may informally use the word "raft".

> Example: A *raft of people* turned up to hear the famous man speak.